# save uploaded files to a session user asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

i have an e commerce site and i have implemented an upload function where users can upload jpeg files, and after, they are able to see it in the grid view immediately. here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                Label2.Text += Session["New"].ToString();
                linkLogout.Visible = true;
                //linkOrderHistory.Visible = true;
                Label2.Visible = true;
                linkViewProfile.Visible = true;
                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));
                List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
                foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
                {
                    files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
                }
                GridView1.DataSource = files;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
        }

    }
    protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + fileName);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        Response.End();
    }
```

what i want to happen is to for example user A has logged in and uploaded a file, it will be only for that user. 
[image]

do i have to put this on a database? any tricks guys? thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes; you need a database.

Comment: thank you! but i want it to be the same still as in the picture. after the upload click, it will be shown immediately in the grid. and now in the database. any idea how to implement it @SLaks thanks sir

Comment: You don't need a database. You could save the images in a folder associated with the user and create a datasource for your grid by enumerating the folder. Too much for one question.

Comment: But that won't add any kind of protection

Comment: @SLaks, using a database does not provide protection either, you still must do the work of preventing direct object access, xss, permissions, etc.

Comment: @Crowcoder what do you mean folder associated with the user? what about if its a new registered customer? will i create a new folder? sorry im not getting it sir

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod, yes, part of your registration process would be to create a folder. I'm not saying this is the one best way. Just saying you don't need a database. When I save files by login I use Azure Blob containers. Beware there is a lot of defensive coding you must do for the functionality you desire.

Comment: will it save me time versus making a database sir @Crowcoder

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod, you are probably going to have a database anyway, even if not for files. Many people save a reference to a file in the database, but the file itself in a folder. So you may end up with a combination. I can't really say what would be faster. If you save to a database one thing you would not have to worry so much about is file name collisions.

Comment: ok got it. can you give me an idea how to do it? will i just add an insert statement and retain my current code? thank you @Crowcoder

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod, like I said, this is really too much for one question. I suggest you google around ([maybe this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-and-save-insert-multiple-files-to-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) ) and ask specific questions instead of solution-wide questions.